# How do I call for specific tumblr responses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, client, response, tumblr

I'm tryibg to only receive certain response from tumplr post or blogs. For example:

```
client = Tumblr::Client.new({
  :consumer_key => 'xxx',
  :consumer_secret => 'xxx',
  :oauth_token => 'xxx',
  :oauth_token_secret => 'xxx'
})

myblog = client.posts

puts myblog["posts"].each do |posts|
    puts posts["id"]
end
```

I get an error:

`/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/tumblr_client-0.8.5/lib/tumblr/blog.rb:32:in`posts': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2) (ArgumentError)
    from tumblr.rb:42:in `<main>''`

...I'm trying to be able to call specific responses instead of getting the whole lots of post info that you normally get back. Please and thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change:

myblog = client.posts

for

myblog = client.posts("yourblog.tumblr.com")

https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr_client/blob/master/README.md

Comment: do you know if there is a specific way to search for posts/blogs?? in other words... if i type/input a keyword then blog names/ posts with pop up??